# Matching 'Date' dataframes in Pandas to enable joins/merging

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, type-conversion

I have two csv files with pandas dataframes with a 'Date' column, which is my desired target to join the two tables (my goal is to join my two csvs by dates and merge matching dataframes by summing them).

The issue is that despite sharing the same month-year format, my first csv abbreviated the years, whereas my desired output would be mm-yyyy (for example, Aug-2012 as opposed to Aug-12).

csv1:

```
0   Oct-12  1154293
1   Nov-12   885773
2   Dec-12  -448704
3   Jan-13   563679
4   Feb-13   555394
5   Mar-13   631974
6   Apr-13   957395
7   May-13  1104047
8   Jun-13   693464
...
```

has 41 rows; i.e. 41 months worth of data between Oct. 12 - Feb. 16

csv2:

```
0   Jan-2009   943690
1   Feb-2009  1062565
2   Mar-2009   210079
3   Apr-2009  -735286
4   May-2009   842933
5   Jun-2009   358691
6   Jul-2009   914953
7   Aug-2009   723427
8   Sep-2009  -837468
...
```

has 86 rows; i.e. 41 months worth of data between Jan. 2009 - Feb. 2016

I tried initially to do something akin to a 'find and replace' function as one would in Excel. 
I tried :

```
findlist = ['12','13','14','15','16']
replacelist = ['2012','2013','2014','2015','2016']

def findReplace(find, replace):
    s = csv1_df.read()
    s = s.replace(Date, replacement)
    csv1_dfc.write(s)

for item, replacement in zip(findlist, replacelist):
    s = s.replace(Date, replacement)
```

But I am getting a

> NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: Please consider reading [mcve] and [edit]ing your post accordingly.

Comment: please share some data from the 2 data frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_datetime` to transform to datetime format, and then `strftime` to adjust your format:

```
df['col_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col_date'], format="%b-%y").dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
```

Input:

```
  col_date      val 
0   Oct-12  1154293
1   Nov-12   885773
2   Dec-12  -448704
3   Jan-13   563679
4   Feb-13   555394
5   Mar-13   631974
6   Apr-13   957395
7   May-13  1104047
8   Jun-13   693464
```

Output:

```
   col_date      val
0  Oct-2012  1154293
1  Nov-2012   885773
2  Dec-2012  -448704
3  Jan-2013   563679
4  Feb-2013   555394
5  Mar-2013   631974
6  Apr-2013   957395
7  May-2013  1104047
8  Jun-2013   693464
```

Note the lower case `y` for 2 digits year and upper case `Y` for 4 digits year.

Comment: Thank you! I was halfway there, missing the "dt.strftime('%b-%Y')" argument.